# Is there a way to emulate --ssl-mode=PREFERRED in pymysql?

Tags: python, pymysql

See SSL modes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl-mode

I've already found how to emulate many SSL modes, for example:

- `DISABLED` (default):

```py
credentials = {
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 3306,
   "user": "user",
   "passwd": "qwerty",
   "database": "test",
}

pymysql.connect(**credentials)
```

- `REQUIRED`:

```py
pymysql.connect(**credentials, ssl={"any_non_empty_dict": True})
```

- `VERIFY_CA`:

```py
pymysql.connect(**credentials, ssl={"ca": "path/to/ca.pem", check_hostname=False})
```

- `VERIFY_IDENTITY`:

```py
pymysql.connect(**credentials, ssl={"ca": "path/to/ca.pem"})
```

But how do I implement `--ssl-mode=PREFERRED`? So, I want `pymysql` (driver) to first check if server accepts SSL, and if not then fallback to unencrypted connection.

If I explicitly disable SSL on MySQL server side as following in `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
ssl=0
```

then I am only able to connect to it using `DISABLED` approach described above.

Comment: Did u find sth out?

Comment: @FrumdaGrayforce not really, I just used some of the pymysql snippets I described here. Most likely it was the strictest one.